# Blazor JSInterop with JSIsolation does not find window.ClassName

Tags: c#, module, blazor, blazor-jsinterop

I am trying to call a method from a `js` file from `Blazor`

I keep getting the following error:

```
Error: Could not find 'TestClass.sayHello' ('TestClass' was undefined).
```

**Js file:**

```js
class TestClass {
  sayHello(s) {
    console.log("Hello " + s);
    return true;
  }
}

window[TestClass.name] = new TestClass();
```

**JsInterop.cs**

```cs
    public IJSRuntime JsRuntime { get; }

    public ExampleJsInterop(IJSRuntime jsRuntime)
    {
        moduleTask = new (() => jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>(
            "import", "./_content/JsTest.lib/exampleJsInterop.js").AsTask());
        JsRuntime = jsRuntime;
    }

    public async ValueTask<bool> SayHello(string name)
    {
        var module = await moduleTask.Value;
        return await module.InvokeAsync<bool>("TestClass.sayHello", name);
    }
```

When I use the jsRuntime directly it is working:

```cs
    public async ValueTask<bool> SayHello(string name)
    {
        var module = await moduleTask.Value;
        return await JsRuntime.InvokeAsync<bool>("TestClass.sayHello", name);
    }
```

I tried different names and const variables with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing normal JS interop, where functions need to be in `window`, and JS isolation, where the method `import` expects a **module**.

Try this instead in your JS file:

```js
export function sayHello(s) {
  console.log("Hello " + s);
  return true;
}
```

And call it directly:

```cs
    public async ValueTask<bool> SayHello(string name)
    {
        var module = await moduleTask.Value;
        return await module.InvokeAsync<bool>("sayHello", name);
    }
```

This is a JS module, it only needs to export the functions that you want to call later.

For more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-6.0#javascript-isolation-in-javascript-modules

Comment: Cool, ty. I can do ```export function sayHello(s) { return window[TestClass.name].sayHello(s) }``` in the original file, if I want to work with classes

Comment: If the answer helped you, don't hesitate to mark it as accepted.